# How to find data value of the parent in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the next structure:

```
<div class="location" onclick="hide();">
    <div class="cat_row"></div>
    <div class="coordinates" data-latitude="51.412176" data-longitude="-0.701547"></div>
</div>
```

And my hide function():

```
var hide = function(){
    var latitude = $(this).children('.coordinates').data('latitude');
    var alert_this = $(this).children('.coordinates').data('latitude');
    alert(alert_this);
}
```

and it prints `undefined`. What is the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in `hide`, `this` refers to the window object not the clicked `.location` element.

One solution is to pass the `location` reference as a parameter to `hide` like

```
<div class="location" onclick="hide(this);">
    <div class="cat_row"></div>
    <div class="coordinates" data-latitude="51.412176" data-longitude="-0.701547"></div>
</div>
```

then

```
var hide = function(el){
    var latitude = $(el).children('.coordinates').data('latitude');
    var alert_this = $(el).children('.coordinates').data('latitude');
    alert(alert_this);
}
```

Cache the selector

```
var hide = function (el) {
    var $cord = $(el).children('.coordinates');
    var latitude = $cord.data('latitude');
    var alert_this = $cord.data('latitude');
    alert(alert_this);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is because when you attach an event handler using an `onclick` attribute the `this` keyword does not refer to the element which raised the event. You have two options. First you can supply `this` as a parameter:

```
<div class="location" onclick="hide(this);">
    <!-- content -->
</div>
```

```js
var hide = function(el) {
    var latitude = $(el).children('.coordinates').data('latitude');
    var alert_this = $(el).children('.coordinates').data('latitude');
    alert(alert_this);
}
```

Alternatively you can attach the event in JS itself:

```
<div class="location">
    <!-- content -->
</div>
```

```js
$('.location').click(function() {
    var latitude = $(this).children('.coordinates').data('latitude');
    var alert_this = $(this).children('.coordinates').data('latitude');
    alert(alert_this);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

First of, look at `Arun P Johny`'s answer. If you use `onclick` Event from the Tag-Element, it will refer to `window`.

I would suggest you to use the click event, so you can use `$(this)`.

```
$( '.location' ).click( function() {
    var coordinates = $( this ).children( '.coordinates' );

    var longitude = coordinates.data( 'longitude' );
    var latitude = coordiantes.data( 'latitude' );

    console.log( 'Latitude: ' + latitude, 'Longitude: ' + longitude );
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass this to hide function:

```
<div class="location" onclick="hide(this);">
    <div class="cat_row"></div>
    <div class="coordinates" data-latitude="51.412176" data-longitude="-0.701547"></div>
</div>
```

```js
var hide = function(self){
    var latitude = $(self).children('.coordinates').data('latitude');
    var alert_this = $(self).children('.coordinates').data('latitude');
    alert(alert_this);
}
```

but it's better to use jQuery to add event:

```
$('.location').click(funtion() {
    var latitude = $(this).children('.coordinates').data('latitude');
    var alert_this = $(this).children('.coordinates').data('latitude');
    alert(alert_this);
});
```